# Sudokus and combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics, sudoku

Considering your suggestions, I have redrawn the 12 X 12 Sudoku so that the twelve rectangles are now visible. The question remains the same:

Can someone construct a 12 X 12 Sudoku with the following rules?
Choose any number on the grid, e.g. A. Then count six numbers horizontally and vertically from A. The difference from the greatest to the smallest should always be equal to 6. The same should be true for the number B or any other number on the 12 X 12 grid.

[image: grid]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Yes it is possible! :D
>
>  [image]
>
>  Notice the pattern? :)